# Plot in NetLogo of different breeds with hatch

Tags: netlogo

I have some troubles in plotting breeds. 
Specifically, I have three breeds, `sellers, buyers` and `cars`. 
The relationship between breeds is something like the following:

```
if breed = buyers [
hatch-cars 1
[ set attribute_1 random-float 1
...]
]
if breed = sellers [
hatch-cars 1
[set attribute_2 random-float 1
...]
```

What I would like to plot is cars depending on the breeds, in order to have two different lines, one for buyers and one for sellers.
I tried with

```
 ask cars with [breed = buyers ][plotxy attribute_1 ticks]
 ask cars with [breed = sellers ] [plotxy attribute_2 ticks]
```

but it does not plot anything and I have not received any error message.
Then, I tried with

```
ask cars [plotxy attribute_1 ticks] 
ask cars [plotxy attribute_2 ticks]
```

and it is almost ok. However, it plots also other points: it seems that it considers all the breeds, `buyers`, `sellers`, and `cars`. 
If I write

```
if breed = buyers [ask cars [plotxy attribute_1 ticks]]
if breed = sellers [ask cars [plotxy attribute_2 ticks]]
```

I receive the following error message: *`You can't use BREED in an observer context, because BREED is turtle/link-only`*.

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by looking at why your first attempt does not plot anything:

```
ask cars with [breed = buyers ][plotxy attribute_1 ticks]
ask cars with [breed = sellers ] [plotxy attribute_2 ticks]
```

When you declare a breed in NetLogo, it creates a special agentset that has the same name as the breed. If you write:

```
breed [ buyers buyer ]
breed [ sellers seller ]
breed [ cars car ]
```

NetLogo creates three special agentsets: `buyers`, `sellers` and `cars`. Each of these agentsets contains only the turtles from the corresponding breed. There also exists the special `turtles` agentset, which contains *all* the turtles in your model, regardless of their breed.

In addition to that, all turtles have a `breed` variable that refer to the breed agentset that they belong to. Each turtle can be either "unbreeded" and have `turtles` as the value of their `breed` variable or belong to one (but no more than one) breed and have that breed's agentset as the value of their `breed` variable.

One thing to know about the `breed` variable is that *you usually don't need to use it.* Writing:

```
ask turtles with [ breed = cars ] [ do-something ]
```

Has the same effect as writing:

```
ask cars [ do-something ]
```

Except that the `ask cars` version is much faster (and more readable) than the `ask turtles with ...` version.

Can we see, now, what's wrong with `ask cars with [breed = buyers ]`? All cars, by definition, have `cars` as the value of their `breed` variable, so the `breed = buyers` condition will always be false. This is why the statement does nothing. (And there is also no reason for it to give you an error message. It's just like asking `turtles with [ color = red ]` to do something when there are no red turtles: nothing happens, but there is nothing wrong with asking.)

Now let's look at your second attempt:

```
ask cars [plotxy attribute_1 ticks] 
ask cars [plotxy attribute_2 ticks]
```

You say that "it seems that it considers all the breeds", but given our understanding of how breeds work, you should be able to see that whatever is wrong with it, it can't be that. As far as I can tell, it should work.

My guess would be that you've been creating extra cars somewhere without realizing  it. Or maybe it's something else. We can't really tell with the information you have given.

(One small side note: it's customary to put ticks on the `x` axis, but you're plotting them on the `y` axis.)

Finally, your last attempt is:

```
if breed = buyers [ask cars [plotxy attribute_1 ticks]]
if breed = sellers [ask cars [plotxy attribute_2 ticks]]
```

We've seen that `breed` is a turtle variable, so it can only be accessed in the context of a particular turtle, and this is why you are getting the warning about trying to use it in the observer context (i.e., by trying to use it outside of a turtle context).

---

In conclusion, I can't offer a direct solution to your problem, but I'm hoping that gaining a better understanding of how breeds work will help you figure out what's wrong.

Maybe one last thing to clarify is that saying something like:

```
ask one-of sellers [ hatch-cars 1 ]
```

does not create any kind of relationship between the newly hatched car and the `sellers` breed. The car doesn't know it's been hatched by a seller. And there is no way to query NetLogo for "all the cars that have been hatched by sellers" unless you keep this information in another variable somewhere. But how to do this is another question (that you're welcome to ask on this site if needed).

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I got you explanation. However, I have still a doubt, i.e. how I could plot two distinct line charts for cars bought by buyers, for instance. Unfortunately, this is still not clear to me.